# Is it possible to apply refactoring using OmniPascal?

Tags: refactoring, omnipascal

I've installed [OmniPascal](http://omnipascal.com/) extension in Visual Studio Code to use it for coding in Delphi and I am loving it. Code completion, parameters hint, go to declarations, all working 100%! Nonetheless, I am missing the refactor commands like rename (CTRL+SHIFT+E). Is that already implemented in OmniPascal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently no refactoring tools implemented in OmniPascal. *Rename* and *Extract method* are planned for the future but there are other features that need to be implemented before OmniPascal can turn into a **reliable** refactoring tool.

As long as OmniPascal doesn't handle all language features correctly (like `with`-blocks or class helpers) the rename command would produce wrong results. You don't want to work with such a refactoring tool.